# 14.04 does not mount or play any DVD

Tags: 14.04, mount, dvd

I read so many related questions and tried so many different things, but nothing seems to work. I am really new with Ubuntu/Linux, and I would be so grateful if someone could help me with that.

The DVD spins for a few seconds, then stops. I can not see it in the finder window, and I can not mount it. I installed a whole bunch of libdvd-things but this also does not seem to work.

Typing `apt-cache policy ubuntu-restricted-extras` gives me

```
ubuntu-restricted-extras:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 60
  Version table:
     60 0
        500 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
```

Typing `apt-cache policy ubuntu-restricted-addons` gives me

```
ubuntu-restricted-addons:
  Installed: 20
  Candidate: 20
  Version table:
 *** 20 0
        500 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Maybe someone can be so kind and help me out.

Thank you!

Regards
Olivia

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Can you open a terminal and type in `apt-cache policy ubuntu-restricted-extras` and `apt-cache policy ubuntu-restricted-addons` and post the results in your original post? Also, can you tell us what additional steps you took to try to solve the issue?

Comment: Hi Musher, thank you! 
Other things I tried were random things I found (for example here in the 'related' box). I know, one should not do stuff without knowing what exactly they will do - I am desperate.

Answer (score 1):

Test this:

Open a terminal.

Run:

```
sudo su 
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras smplayer
```

Visit:
http://download.videolan.org/ubuntu/trusty/

Download and install:

```
http://download.videolan.org/ubuntu/trusty/libdvdcss-dev_1.2.13-0_amd64.deb
http://download.videolan.org/ubuntu/trusty/libdvdcss2_1.2.13-0_amd64.deb

sudo su 
cd /home/<user-name>/Downloads
dpkg -i *.deb
```

Run Smplayer for play dvds.

Comment: thanks, kyodake. it still does not work though. the DVD/CD is not mounted when i put it in. and Smplayer does not find anything that it could play.

Comment: `libdvdcss-dev` is unnecessary and it would be safer to call `dpkg -i ~/Downloads/libdvdcss2_1.2.13-0_amd64.deb` instead of using wildcards in case there are other Debian packages.